# Binary Bomb Lab Phase 6 : I was caught up in the last part

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

This is asm code for binary bomb Phase_6.

```
00000000004010ca <phase_6>:
  4010ca:   41 56                   push   %r14
  4010cc:   41 55                   push   %r13
  4010ce:   41 54                   push   %r12
  4010d0:   55                      push   %rbp
  4010d1:   53                      push   %rbx
  4010d2:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp
  4010d6:   48 8d 74 24 30          lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
  4010db:   e8 68 04 00 00          callq  401548 <read_six_numbers>
  4010e0:   4c 8d 64 24 30          lea    0x30(%rsp),%r12
  4010e5:   4d 8d 74 24 14          lea    0x14(%r12),%r14
  4010ea:   41 bd 01 00 00 00       mov    $0x1,%r13d
  4010f0:   eb 28                   jmp    40111a <phase_6+0x50>
  4010f2:   e8 1b 04 00 00          callq  401512 <explode_bomb>
  4010f7:   eb 30                   jmp    401129 <phase_6+0x5f>
  4010f9:   e8 14 04 00 00          callq  401512 <explode_bomb>
  4010fe:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  401102:   83 fb 05                cmp    $0x5,%ebx
  401105:   7f 0b                   jg     401112 <phase_6+0x48>
  401107:   8b 44 9c 30             mov    0x30(%rsp,%rbx,4),%eax
  40110b:   39 45 00                cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
  40110e:   75 ee                   jne    4010fe <phase_6+0x34>
  401110:   eb e7                   jmp    4010f9 <phase_6+0x2f>
  401112:   49 83 c5 01             add    $0x1,%r13
  401116:   49 83 c4 04             add    $0x4,%r12
  40111a:   4c 89 e5                mov    %r12,%rbp
  40111d:   41 8b 04 24             mov    (%r12),%eax
  401121:   83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
  401124:   83 f8 05                cmp    $0x5,%eax
  401127:   77 c9                   ja     4010f2 <phase_6+0x28>
  401129:   4d 39 f4                cmp    %r14,%r12
  40112c:   74 05                   je     401133 <phase_6+0x69>
  40112e:   4c 89 eb                mov    %r13,%rbx
  401131:   eb d4                   jmp    401107 <phase_6+0x3d>
  401133:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  401138:   8b 4c b4 30             mov    0x30(%rsp,%rsi,4),%ecx
  40113c:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  401141:   ba f0 42 60 00          mov    $0x6042f0,%edx
  401146:   83 f9 01                cmp    $0x1,%ecx
  401149:   7e 0b                   jle    401156 <phase_6+0x8c>
  40114b:   48 8b 52 08             mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
  40114f:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  401152:   39 c8                   cmp    %ecx,%eax
  401154:   75 f5                   jne    40114b <phase_6+0x81>
  401156:   48 89 14 f4             mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,8)
  40115a:   48 83 c6 01             add    $0x1,%rsi
  40115e:   48 83 fe 06             cmp    $0x6,%rsi
  401162:   75 d4                   jne    401138 <phase_6+0x6e>
  401164:   48 8b 1c 24             mov    (%rsp),%rbx
  401168:   48 8b 44 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
  40116d:   48 89 43 08             mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
  401171:   48 8b 54 24 10          mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdx
  401176:   48 89 50 08             mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
  40117a:   48 8b 44 24 18          mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
  40117f:   48 89 42 08             mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
  401183:   48 8b 54 24 20          mov    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
  401188:   48 89 50 08             mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
  40118c:   48 8b 44 24 28          mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
  401191:   48 89 42 08             mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
  401195:   48 c7 40 08 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
  40119c:   00 
  40119d:   bd 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%ebp
  4011a2:   eb 09                   jmp    4011ad <phase_6+0xe3>
  4011a4:   48 8b 5b 08             mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
  4011a8:   83 ed 01                sub    $0x1,%ebp
  4011ab:   74 11                   je     4011be <phase_6+0xf4>
  4011ad:   48 8b 43 08             mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
  4011b1:   8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
  4011b3:   39 03                   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
  4011b5:   7d ed                   jge    4011a4 <phase_6+0xda>
  4011b7:   e8 56 03 00 00          callq  401512 <explode_bomb>
  4011bc:   eb e6                   jmp    4011a4 <phase_6+0xda>
  4011be:   48 83 c4 50             add    $0x50,%rsp
  4011c2:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4011c3:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4011c4:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  4011c6:   41 5d                   pop    %r13
  4011c8:   41 5e                   pop    %r14
  4011ca:   c3                      retq
```

This requires analysis to enter 6 non-identical numbers, less than 6 and separated by spaces.
like `%d %d %d %d %d %d`.

So I entered `1 2 3 4 5 6`, and try `until *0x04011a2`.

```
(gdb) until *0x04011a2
0x00000000004011a2 in phase_6 ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x4011a2 <phase_6+216>:      jmp    0x4011ad <phase_6+227>
(gdb) x/3x $rbx
0x6042f0 <node1>:       0x000002d8      0x00000001      0x00604300
(gdb) x/3x *($rbx+8)
0x604300 <node2>:       0x000003cf      0x00000002      0x00604310
(gdb) x/3x *(*($rbx+8)+8)
0x604310 <node3>:       0x00000369      0x00000003      0x00604320
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*($rbx+8)+8)+8)
0x604320 <node4>:       0x000001cc      0x00000004      0x00604330
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*(*($rbx+8)+8)+8)+8)
0x604330 <node5>:       0x00000265      0x00000005      0x00604340
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*(*(*($rbx+8)+8)+8)+8)+8)
0x604340 <node6>:       0x00000294      0x00000006      0x00000000
```

Based on the above results, I entered `4 5 6 1 3 2` and `2 3 1 6 5 4` but both blew up. What am I wrong?
Unlike other similar bomblab phase_6 problems, there does not appear to be any parts that show such as `f(x) = N - x`...

Did I misunderstand something and solve it?

Comment: Did you figure out what the inputted numbers are for? They are used for a specific purpose and are no longer needed by the time execution reaches 0x4011a2. So don't try to find patterns in the input sequence. You can use GDB to see what's happening but honestly, a real-life RE tool (like IDA or Ghidra, both free) will make you solve this challenge in a matter of minutes without the need to resort to dynamic analysis.